# Is there a way to easily determine that a shape drawn in canvas has been clicked on?

Tags: html, canvas, interaction

I am learning how to use the HTML5 canvas right now. I have a simple script which draws circles along a horizontal line.

I would like to enhance my script to be more interactive. I want to be able to click on one of the circles along the line and this causes the data linked to that circle to be shown as text on the canvas.

Is this easily achieveable in the canvas? From the tutorials I have looked at I gather that I have to put an onclick on the canvas itself. From there I was guessing that I would have to work out where my mouse cursor has been clicked and somehow work out which circle contains my clicked point.

Are there any snippets of code or pointers that can help me with this? Alternatively, is the canvas really not suitable for this type of problem? Any comments are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can add mouse event handling by using the isPointInPath method of canvas. Something like this below (untested).

```
// add click event handler to canvas
// on click
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseX = e.clientX - rect.left;
var mouseY = e.clientY - rect.top;

ctx.beginPath()
// draw stuff
if (ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY)) {
  // handle click
}
```

This will recognize any shape, which is very useful if you are drawing anything other than rectangles and circles.  However, the major drawback to this is that you have to redraw on every click (or mousemove if you are adding mouseovers). In my experience I can get away with drawing at least 300 objects before I start seeing issues with performance.

I should also note there is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=405300) in firefoxes implementation of isPointInPath that remains unfixed for some reason. But happily the fix is easy enough

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.isPointInPath_mozilla = function( x, y )
{
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1){
    this.save();
    this.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
    var ret = this.isPointInPath( x, y );
    this.restore();
  } else
    var ret = this.isPointInPath( x, y );

  return ret;
}
```

just replace ctx.isPointInPath(x,y) with ctx.isPointInPath_mozilla(x,y) and everything works

Answer (score 2):

Canvas uses raster graphics. Once you have drawn a circle, it no longer has an identity as a circle - you just have a bunch of pixels. You need to keep track of all shapes yourself.

If you use vector graphics, like SVG, the shapes retain an identity and can be manipulated. It's probably going to be easier this way.

Answer (score 0):

You create click event for canvas and in handler you must calculate (some basic math) if user click on the circle. The other way is not to use canvas but SVG there are libraries like [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this for mobile device canvas drawing and then shape matching.

My procedure was.

Declare a 2D array based on the number of canvas height and width in pixels.

Fill the Array with 0

For the mousemove event (Desktop browser) track the position. You will get a X,Y Value.
in your 2D array put 1 in row and column (X and Y value).

After drawing you will get a 2D binary image Array.

Now the fun part:

Try Image momentam or any other suitable method from this link. http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/Tutorial--Algorithms%20for%202-D%20Object%20Recognition.pdf

If you save some 2D drawn shapes array and match with the current drawn image, you will be able to find a nearest match. Try to find a suitable threshold if user drawn a completely different shape.

I hope that will help.